# Bootstrap carousel shows enlarged images on iphone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would be really appreciate if you can help me with the next issue. 
I have template with Bootstrap carousel on the frontpage. Size of the images shows ok on the laptop, but when I open it in Iphone - images still big and it looks like enlarged picture. http://c2n.me/itAJbn.jpg

Css code is

```
#main-slider {
  position: relative;
}

#main-slider .carousel h2 {


 }
#main-slider .carousel .btn {
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#main-slider .carousel .btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#main-slider .carousel .boxed {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
}
#main-slider .carousel .item {
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 600ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out 600ms;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out 600ms;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 600ms;
}


#main-slider .carousel .item:first-child {
  top: auto;`enter code here`
  position: relative;
```

html

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type'=>'zee_slider', 'orderby' => 'menu_order','order' => 'ASC' );
$sliders = get_posts( $args );
$total_sliders = count($sliders);
?>
<section id="main-slider" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="carousel slide wet-asphalt" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php for($i = 0; $i<$total_sliders; $i++){ ?>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i ?>" class="<?php echo ($i==0)?'active':'' ?>"></li>
            <?php } ?>

        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php foreach ($sliders as $key => $slider) { 

                $full_img           =   wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $slider->ID ), 'full');

                $slider_position    =   get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_position', true );

                $boxed              =   (get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_boxed', true )=='yes') ? 'boxed' : '';

                $has_button         =   (get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_button_text', true )=='') ? false : true;

                $button             =   get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_button_text', true );

                $button_url         =   get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_button_url', true );

                $video_url          =   get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_video_link', true );

                $video_type         =   get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_video_type', true );

                $bg_image_url       =   get_post_meta($slider->ID, 'slider_background_image', true );

                $background_image   =   'background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_url($bg_image_url).')';

                $columns            =   false;



                if( !empty($image_url) or !empty($video_url) ){

                    $columns        =   true;
                }


                if( $video_type=='youtube' ) {

                    $embed_code = '<iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' . get_video_ID( $video_url ) . '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

                } elseif( $video_type=='vimeo' ) {
                    $embed_code = '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/' . get_video_ID( $video_url ) . '?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=a22c2f" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
                }

                if( $full_img ){

                    $embed_code     = '<img src="' . $full_img[0] . '" alt="">';
                    $columns        =   true;
                }


                ?>

                <div class="item <?php echo ($key==0) ? 'active' : '' ?>" style="<?php echo ( $bg_image_url ) ? $background_image : '' ?>">
                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="<?php echo ($columns) ? 'col-sm-6' : 'col-sm-12'  ?>">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered <?php echo $slider_position ?> " >
                                    <h2 class="<?php echo $boxed ?> animation animated-item-1">
                                        <?php echo $slider->post_title ?>
                                    </h2>

                                    <p class="<?php echo $boxed ?> animation animated-item-2">
                                        <?php echo do_shortcode( $slider->post_content ) ?>
                                    </p>

                                    <?php if( $has_button ){ ?>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="<?php echo $button_url ?>"><?php echo $button ?></a>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php if($columns){ ?>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                                <div class="centered" style="margin-top: 129px;">
                                    <div class="embed-container">
                                        <?php echo $embed_code; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->


                <?php } // endforeach ?>

            </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
        </div><!--/.carousel-->
        <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </section>
```

Comment: We need the html too :)

Comment: I just added :) When I change height at the (#main-slider .carousel .item) from 650px to auto or to 100% it leads to this http://c2n.me/itCUSC.png. So I stuck on this issue